# How to test scalability and high availability of Kaa?

Tags: kaa

I need to collect the data and make analysis of scalability and high availability of Kaa IOT using Kaa cluster. What tool i need or any command if possible to represent its simulated data. So here i need two tools. first is tool for sending simulated data. second is tool to monitor scalability and HA.

Answer (score 0):

For simulated data uploading you can use Data Collection demo application available from the Kaa Sandbox or Sample Applications repository on GitHub. With small modifications it can generate as much data as you need.

For the Kaa server load monitoring please read [Kaa Performance monitoring](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Performance+monitoring) documentation page. Please ignore its relation to Kaa 0.9 as it also aplies to the Kaa 0.10 (the new documentation lacks the respective page occasionally).